# Tracking with XeTeX via LetterSpace

Tags: xetex, fontspec

When I use PDFLaTeX I have a setup using [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) and a font available in small caps (eg \usepackage{lmodern}),

```
\usepackage[
protrusion=true,
expansion=true,
kerning=true,
spacing=true,
tracking=true,
factor=1100,
stretch=40,
shrink=10
]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding={*}, family= *, shape=fsc}{16}
```

I would like the same set-up for XeLaTeX (as much as possible). I know that XeLaTeX only allows protusion with microtype but I have a lot of `\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape` in my commands (for sections and so on) and I want to enable the tracking globally just as microtype does it with PDFLaTeX.
 I know I can use `LetterSpace` to do it locally, but is there a way to do it only once and for all?

Comment: Perhaps with `\defaultfontfeatures{LetterSpace=…}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the scheme for Linux Libertine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  UprightFeatures={
    SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=50},
  },
  BoldFeatures={
    SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineOB},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=50},
  },
  ItalicFeatures={
    SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineOI},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=50},
  },
  BoldItalicFeatures={
    SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineOBI},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=50},
  },
]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

This is text and \textsc{This is in Small Caps}

Don't use the following combinations, please:

{\scshape\bfseries This is Bold Small Caps}

{\scshape\itshape This is Italic Small Caps}

{\scshape\bfseries\itshape This is Bold Italic Small Caps}

\end{document}
```

Adapt to your setting. The tracking is set to 50, which is certainly too much, just for clearly showing the effect.

[image]